# Can't Start/Restart MySQL. Even After Reboot

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

Can anybody please help me? I'm afraid of losing my data. MySQL just stop and when I try to restart or start it, I can't. When I look at the log file, I see the following info:

```
150712  6:36:15 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150712  6:36:15 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150712  6:36:15 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150712  6:36:15 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150712  6:36:15 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150712  6:36:15 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150712  6:36:15 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 4.0G
150712  6:36:15 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150712  6:36:15 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 14001211870
150712  6:36:15  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 14001212249
InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 1 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 3133200
150712  6:36:15  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
150712  6:36:15  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 313307B, 1 rows to undo
150712  6:36:15  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
150712  6:36:15  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140519574923008 in file fut0lst.ic line 83
InnoDB: Failing assertion: addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
10:36:15 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=4194304
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=1000
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 6171907 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x20)[0x7fce853e8c80]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3d5)[0x7fce852d2f15]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340)[0x7fce84063340]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x39)[0x7fce836bacc9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7fce836be0d8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x274ab1)[0x7fce8516cab1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x60d818)[0x7fce85505818]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5982c9)[0x7fce854902c9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5ac63a)[0x7fce854a463a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5a4de4)[0x7fce8549cde4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5a5f90)[0x7fce8549df90]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5a0a7f)[0x7fce85498a7f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x64e76a)[0x7fce8554676a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x64edf4)[0x7fce85546df4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x59f323)[0x7fce85497323]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x59f89e)[0x7fce8549789e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8182)[0x7fce8405b182]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fce8377e47d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

I've search the internet for possible solution but I'm afraid that I will be reading the wrong article.

Could anyone please suggest what is the best and first thing to do?

Comment: Did you follow the hint at the bottom at your stack trace? Also the ones in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

First and best:

> This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

Spin up a new system somewhere and try to bring your database online using it. You can copy the entire contents of your mysql directory tree over the top the new one.

If that fails too.

> InnoDB: Failing assertion: addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA
>   InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
>   InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.

You should submit a bug report.

> InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
>   InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be 
>   InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
>   InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
>   InnoDB: about forcing recovery.

That seems like good advice too.

> It is also possible that this binary
>   or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt,

You can verify the binaries checksums using the contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/*.md5sums` and the [md5sum](http://linux.die.net/man/1/md5sum) utility

> The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
>   information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.

More sound advice.

I would also be reaching for my backups.

Comment: Thanks lain. I have tried this option innodb_force_recovery = 3 since 1 & 2 don't work. I can now access my database but it is still in read only mode. Should I backup the database drop it and restore the database back or is there any other option to fix the database? Because removing the force recovery will result in the same scenario, that is I can't start mysql.

Answer (score 0):

just in case you can't fix that problem and you have innodb tables you want to recover the data, you can use percona toolkit (https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-innodb-data-recovery-tools).

The documentation is quite nice and the tool works great.

Regards.